# Where is SIGHASH_TYPE serialized in SegWit?

Tags: signature, consensus

When preparing or verifying a signature, a transaction pre-image is created in memory. This pre-image exists purely for the purpose of creating a signature and is not published to the blockchain. At the end of this pre-image is a 4 bytes `SIGHASH_TYPE`.

When serializing the resulting transaction, the `SIGHAH_TYPE` is truncated to one byte and added at the end of each signature. The remaining 4 bytes are not put at the end of the final transaction ([here's why](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48108/why-are-sighash-flags-signed-as-4-bytes-when-only-1-byte-is-included-in-the-tran), probably).

How does this work with SegWit? Is 1 byte appended to the signature in the the same way, but in the witness data rather than the legacy part of the transaction? It's not immediately obvious to me based on the examples in [BIP143](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is 1 byte appended to the signature in the the same way, but in the witness data rather than the legacy part of the transaction?

Yes. The signature serialization (which includes the sighash type) remains exactly the same.

Look at the [first example in BIP 143](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki#native-p2wpkh), the generated signature (before serialization) is `304402203609e17b84f6a7d30c80bfa610b5b4542f32a8a0d5447a12fb1366d7f01cc44a0220573a954c4518331561406f90300e8f3358f51928d43c212a8caed02de67eebee`. When it is serialized, it becomes `47304402203609e17b84f6a7d30c80bfa610b5b4542f32a8a0d5447a12fb1366d7f01cc44a0220573a954c4518331561406f90300e8f3358f51928d43c212a8caed02de67eebee01`. Notice how when serialized there is an additional byte appended to the signature; that is the sighash type.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. I think the example would be more readable if the size, signature, sighash type and pubkey are put on seperate lines.